# How to add selected images in gridview in android

Tags: android, arrays

I want to select some images from gallery and show in gridview. I have used Filepicker library. Its working but the mai problem i am facing is that images are not showing in gridview after selection. I show you my code. Please help me.
This is my Fragment Class

```
   fabPhotosAdd.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            FilePickerBuilder.getInstance().setSelectedFiles(arrayList)
                    .setActivityTheme(R.style.Theme_AppCompat_Light).pickPhoto(getActivity());
        }
    });

 @Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    switch (requestCode) {
        case FilePickerConst.REQUEST_CODE:
            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK && data != null) {
                arrayList = data.getStringArrayListExtra(FilePickerConst.KEY_SELECTED_PHOTOS);
                PhotoFragmentModel model;
                ArrayList<PhotoFragmentModel> list = new ArrayList<>();
                try {
                    for (String path : arrayList) {
                        model = new PhotoFragmentModel();
                        model.setName(path.substring(path.lastIndexOf("/") + 1));
                        model.setUri(Uri.fromFile(new File(path)));
                        list.add(model);
                    }
                    gridPhotos.setAdapter(new PhotoFragmentAdapter(getActivity(), list));
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Total : " + String.valueOf(list.size()), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                } catch (Exception e) {

                }
            }
    }
}
```

PhotoFragmentAdapter.java

```
public class PhotoFragmentAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

private Context context;
private ArrayList<PhotoFragmentModel> arrayList;
private LayoutInflater inflater;
private ImageView ivPhoto;
private TextView tvName;

public PhotoFragmentAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<PhotoFragmentModel> arrayList) {
    this.context = context;
    this.arrayList = arrayList;
    inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return arrayList.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int i) {
    return arrayList.get(i);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int i) {
    return i;
}

@Override
public View getView(int i, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup) {

    view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.item_photo_fragment, null);
    final PhotoFragmentModel model = (PhotoFragmentModel) this.getItem(i);

    ivPhoto = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.iv_item_photo);
    tvName = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tv_item_name);

    Picasso.with(context).load(model.getUri()).fit().into(ivPhoto);
    tvName.setText(model.getName());
    return view;
}
```

}

Selection is working perfectly, but after selection Images are not showing in gridview. This is the main problem. if anyone can help me or guide me some other library, i will thankful him.

Comment: Check if your arrayList is not null and arrayList.size() must be greater than 0. Also check if filepath which u are adding to list is a valid and image exists in filesystem.

Comment: I already checked it. It work fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
model.setUri(Uri.fromFile(new File(path)));
```

This one can not solve in case :special character of folder.

**Try this**

```
model.setUri(Uri.fromFile(new File(getPath(uri)));

public String getPath(Uri uri) 
    {
        String[] projection = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };
        Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(uri, projection, null, null, null);
        if (cursor == null) return null;
        int column_index =             cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        String s=cursor.getString(column_index);
        cursor.close();
        return s;
    }
```

oh now i get it the main reason of not working is

```
final PhotoFragmentModel model = (PhotoFragmentModel) this.getItem(i);
```

you can directly call the arraylist item of index

```
Picasso.with(context).load(arrayList.get(i).getUri()).fit().into(ivPhoto);
```

Comment: Its not making any effect. Problem is remain same.